# pygame TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying python with a simple game, but encounter this error.
The codes as below:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired by the ship."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color
    
        # Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set correct position.
        # self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,
        #     self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(left=0, top=0, width=self.settings.bullet_width,
            height=self.settings.bullet_height)
        # ...
```

Then the error says:

> File "my_codes/alien_invasion/bullet.py", line 15, in **init**
> self.rect = pygame.Rect(left=0, top=0, width=self.settings.bullet_width,
> TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

If I change the line as below it works fine:

```
self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,
    self.settings.bullet_height)
```

I don't under stand why only positional args passing works here.
I would appreciate it if you can help me.

Comment: Take a look at this on line 43 https://github.com/CTPUG/pygame_cffi/blob/master/pygame/rect.py

EDIT: Its expecting a tuple I think that's why

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand it now.

Comment: If you need you could make a generator class that takes keywords and converts them to the proper Rect format as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> [...]  A Rect can be created from a combination of left, top, width, and height values. Rects can also be created from python objects that are already a Rect or have an attribute named "rect".

See an implementation of the constructor of `pygame.Rect` (from [`pygame_cffi`](https://github.com/CTPUG/pygame_cffi/blob/master/pygame/rect.py)):

```py
class Rect(object):
    # [...]

    def __init__(self, *args):
        # [...]
```

Therefore, you cannot specify the arguments with keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's initialized using a list, no wondor key words aren't allowed.